# Añadir borde alrededor de texto

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Para añadir borde a texto y títulos, estoy usando `text-shadow` y añadiendo múltiples sombras para simular ese efecto:

```css
div {
  font-family:verdana;
  font-size:50px;
  color:white;
  text-shadow: 1px  0px 0px black,
               0px  1px 0px black,
              -1px  0px 0px black,
               0px -1px 0px black;
}
```

```html
<div>TEXTO CON BORDE</div>
```

Este método funciona bien si el borde es de un sólo píxel, pero no funciona tan bien si el borde es más grueso, ya que habría que añadir más sombras y aún así se ven saltos en las esquinas de las letras:

```css
div {
  font-family:verdana;
  font-size:50px;
  color:white;
  text-shadow: 3px  0px 0px black,
               0px  3px 0px black,
              -3px  0px 0px black,
               0px -3px 0px black;
}
```

```html
<div>TEXTO CON BORDE</div>
```

Mi pregunta: **¿Existe algún modo de solucionar este problema?** (aparte de añadir más sombras). Y a ser posible, que sea un método que funcione en los principales navegadores y que sea estándar (sé que existe `text-stroke` pero no funciona en IE/Edge o Firefox y no es estándar).

Comment: esta permitido el uso de svg como enfoque alternativo?

Comment: @rnrneverdies Sí. De hecho, es una alternativa que me estaba planteando ([usando svg inline](https://jsfiddle.net/juzd2jrk/)). El principal problema que me encuentro con eso es que las líneas deben estar "definidas" (lo cual puede que no sea tanto problema)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hasta donde se, hay que esperar que `text-stroke` este soportado por la mayoría de los navegadores. Mientras tanto existe una solución alternativa, utilizar *SVG* inline.

Ejemplo:

```html
<svg width="500" height="75" viewBox="0 0 500 75">
  <text x="0" y="55" style="fill: white; stroke: #000; stroke-width: 3px; font-size: 50px; font-weight: bold; font-family: verdana ">
    Texto con borde
  </text>
</svg>
```

Por los comentarios:

Hice varias pruebas, la mejor opcion que encuentro para que se adapte a lo alto es utilizar [viewBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) y `height` de 100% en el elemento.

```css
.contenedor {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">  
<svg height="100%" viewBox="0 0 500 75">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" style="fill: red;" />
  <text x="25" y="55" style="fill: white; stroke: #000; stroke-width: 3px; font-size: 50px; font-weight: bold; font-family: verdana ">
    Texto con borde
  </text>
</svg>
</div>
```

**Ojo!** Esta es una solucion ***no*** intercambiable con `text-stroke`, ya que por ejemplo no es factible cambiar el estilo de solo una palabra de un parrafo.

Comment: Ésta es la alternativa que me estaba planteando, pero me encuentro con un problema de integración con el resto de los elementos. ¿Hay alguna manera para que el alto se ajuste automáticamente al contenido? (Si no, me quedan espacio en blanco por encima y/o por debajo del SVG a no ser que especifique el alto)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro luego de varias pruebas, la mejor solución que encontre  es que le des un height="100%" al elemento. Te dejo un ejemplo en la rta.

Answer (score 2):

Hasta el momento la solución más próxima es con `text-shadow` y una familia `sans-serif` puedes obtener un efecto interesante.

```css
body { background-color: #fff; }
p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 68px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 2px 0 0 #000, -2px 0 0 #000, 0 2px 0 #000, 0 -2px 0 #000, 1px 1px #000, -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000;
}
```

```html
<p>StackOverFlowES</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

A la fecha no hay una solución "perfecta" para todos los browsers. Según veo en el sitio http://caniuse.com/#search=text-stroke, ni Firefox, Internet Explorer, Edge ni Opera Mini, soportan el método `text-stroke`.

La solución que empleas con `text-shadow` es la que se recomienda como la más aproximada, pero como tú lo has probado, sólo funciona correctamente si el grosor del borde es `1px`, si es superior, los bordes no están bien definidos en las esquinas de las letras.

Comment: Esta respuesta me parece el texto de la pregunta reescrito de manera diferente (la principal diferencia es el enlace a caniuse). Realmente no creo que ofrezca nada nuevo.